# Removing '$' from the output

Tags: sql

I am having the column as price, where entries are $3000,$4500 and so on.
I want to remove the dollar $ like it should only print 3000,4000 etc.
How to achieve his?

Comment: you need to use the replace function on that column (replace $ with empty string).

Comment: are you storing it as varchar?

Comment: yes using it as a varchar

Comment: Are you storing the price as a string (e.g. a `varchar` or similar)? If so, you might want to store it as a decimal instead - it's a more natural datatype for currency. Some DBMSs have a specific `money` datatype (SQL Server for example)

Comment: since sql functions can be vendor en version specific, it's a good idea to tag your question with the appropriate tag, like [mysql] , [sql server]...

Comment: You should make changes in your DB. Price should be stored in Integer/Double type column and you should store currency in diff columns (in case using multiple currency). This will make it easy to some calculation in db (in case needed).

Comment: `replace(price,'$','')`, but I recommend storing prices as a numeric data type.

Comment: You should store price as `money` or `smallmoney`

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
UPDATE your_table SET your_column = REPLACE(your_column,'$','')
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT RIGHT(ColumnName, LEN(ColumnName) - 1) from TableName where ColumnName is not null

You can remove the where clause is you Column have notnull constraint on it.